# How can I find out which repository a given installed package was installed from?

Tags: apt, software-installation, package-management, repository

How can I find out which repository a given installed package or program was installed from? I can see all the packages on my install with `dpkg -l`. Is there a method to see where they were sourced from?

Comment: Does [this help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8560/how-do-i-find-out-which-repository-a-package-comes-from)?

Answer (score 9):

`apt` doesn’t keep track of the repository from which it obtained a package. The best you can do is determine which repositories contain a given package *now*, as far as `apt` is aware (so technically, the last time `apt update` was run).

To see which repositories `apt` considers for a given package, use `apt policy`; for example:

```
$ apt policy rr
rr:
  Installed: 5.2.0-1
  Candidate: 5.2.0-2
  Version table:
     5.2.0-2 100
        100 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.2.0-1 100
        100 /usr/var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.4.0-2+b1 500
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

This output tells me `apt` knows about these `rr` versions:

- 4.4.0-2+b1, which is available from my configured Debian 9 (Stretch) repository;
- 5.2.0-1, which is the currently-installed version, and is not available from any currently-configured repository;
- 5.2.0-2, which is available from my configured testing and unstable repositories.

Versions with no matching repository can happen in a variety of circumstances:

- a repository used to host the version, but no longer does (this happens if you don’t upgrade your packages, and new versions are uploaded to the repositories you track);
- the package was installed from a repository, and then the repository was removed;
- the package was installed from a source other than a repository (this is the case here: the package I have installed is my locally-built version).

Comment: Thanks. How does apt know which repository has update for an installed program?

Comment: Each repository provides an index of the packages it contains.