# Installing errors on wine32: libsystemd0 and libapt-pkg6.0 dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, wine

When trying to install wine32, I'm getting

```
❯ sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0
 util-linux : PreDepends: libsystemd0
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I just don't understand how `libsystemd0` and `libapt-pkg6.0` can be the problem they're both installed.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version      Architecture Description
+++-===================-============-============-==================================
ii  libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 2.5.0        amd64        package management runtime library
ii  libsystemd0:amd64   250.4-1      amd64        systemd utility library
```

How can I resolve this? How can I trouble shoot it in the future?

---

When I run `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` it says `i386`

---

Here is the apt policy for `libcap2`

```
❯ apt policy libcap2:{amd64,i386}
libcap2:
  Installed: 100:2.48-1
  Candidate: 100:2.48-1
  Version table:
 *** 100:2.48-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:2.44-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
libcap2:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.44-1
  Version table:
     1:2.44-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t install `wine32` because it’s a 32-bit package (`i386` in your case, but it could also be `armhf`) and it needs a `libcap2` package matching its architecture.

`libcap2` is a multi-arch package, so this is normally not a problem: `amd64` and `i386` versions can be installed in parallel, as indeed can versions for any Debian architecture. But multi-arch packaged must be installed in the same version on all architectures. `apt` can’t find a version of `libcap2:i386` matching your version of `libcap2:amd64`, so it considers removing the latter, and all its dependencies, which leads to the impossible situation described in your initial error.

As far the investigation goes, the first thing to check with multi-arch scenarios is the configured foreign architectures. I also checked on my end that the package versions in the error were current (to ensure the system didn’t need an `apt upgrade`). Then, given the bizareness of the situation in the error, there’s not much point looking further there; instead, attempting the installation again with the package resolver’s debug output is likely to give some indication of what’s going wrong. The first issue there involves `libcap2` with an impossible version (no package in the repositories has an epoch of 100), which suggests a version mismatch across architectures:

```
Investigating (0) libsystemd0:amd64 < 250.4-1 @ii K Ib >
Broken libsystemd0:amd64 PreDepends on libcap2:amd64 < 100:2.48-1 @ii pR > (>= 1:2.24-9~)
  Considering libcap2:amd64 0 as a solution to libsystemd0:amd64 611
  Added libcap2:amd64 to the remove list
```

To fix this, you’ll either have to provide a matching `i386` version of your `libcap2`, or downgrade `libcap2:amd64` to the version in the repositories.

Comment: Is this a bug upstream that we should file? How can I find a version of libcap2:amd64 that satisfies libcap2:i386, and shouldn't the resolver know that it can downgrade one archs to match another arch if that's the only option? Is this a problem with the resolver?

Comment: Also where did the epoch of 100 come from?

Comment: Packages are never considered for downgrades unless you configure their pin-priorities to allow that. This isn’t an upstream bug. I don’t know where the epoch came from; perhaps from the repository [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1328404/412264)?

Comment: Ugz. This is a problem caused by rancher. Hrm. I have another question but I think it would be a good follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen's answer is right on the investigation (as always),

- Stephen had [another stellar answer here which is the second part I needed to investigate this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478273/3285). The epoch 500 and the fact that the package wasn't in a current repository (as determined from the should raise the question where I got it from.)
- Stephen basically [determine it was from another repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/1328404/412264). Specifically I had a repo, specified in `devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable.list` which had one line

  ```
  # deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/Debian_Testing/ /
  ```

  So basically, I had that repository, it got commented out and the package it installed was pinned to `2.48` and doesn't provide i386.

## Case-specific solution

In this case, I tried downgrading the package first

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2=1:2.44-1
```

Then I was able to install `wine32`, and other weirdness stopped.