# How did this Rancher/SUSE packaging problem go so wrong?

Tags: debian, apt, repository, version

This is like a retrospective on a problem I just narrowed down. I believe there *must* be some kind of solution in the package manager to provide a *better* user-experience. I'm going to describe what happened, I would like to know,

- How it can be made better, is there something SUSE can do to provide a better user-experience for Debian users?
- How I as a Debian user can run into fewer of these problems.

The debugging of the original problem happened on this question, [*"Installing errors on wine32: libsystemd0 and libapt-pkg6.0 dependencies"*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/703750/3285).

## Description of problem

At some point in time I had this repository installed on my machine in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable.list`

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/Debian_Testing/ /
```

When I had that repository enabled, I must have installed `libcap2`, this installed `100:2.48-1 100` for amd64. I believe what happened was an upgrade disabled this repository. And after it was disabled this package stuck around and prevented the installation of repos libcap2 which was stuck at 2.44 but provided the i386 arch which would have resolved my problems.

[I solved this by downgrading the package explicitly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703832/3285)

## Can Rancher/SUSE do anything better?

It would seem to me at some point in time `libcap2` version `100:2.48-1` was installed. Is there anyway Rancher can make this play better with system?

## Can I do anything better?

It's my understanding that this repo was commented out during an upgrade. Is there a method to remove packages installed from third party repos before dist-upgrading? Or, is it such that any time a repo is commented out, or the rendered EOL and left unmaintained by upstream all of the things installed (which can't be audited) must be removed by hand? Is there some kind of process one can go through after removing or commenting a repository to better clean up this stuff?